# How to run Power Automate's Schedule Cloud flow's Desktop Flow action by connecting to VM that doesn't allow user/password login?

Tags: virtual-machine, power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I am trying to use the Desktop Flow action in a Scheduled Cloud flow run so I can run my PAD flows automatically in the VM. My issue is whether I am trying to connect via an on premise gateway or directly to the machine I am completely unable to connect and am get the "check your credentials" error. I have followed this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/gateway-desktop-flow/) using my Azure AD login and I am wondering if this has to do with the fact that I am unable to login into the VM with user/password credentials. I am only able to login by using my fingerprint or my 4 digit pin number. I have looked into many forums/discussions and have asked this question on [Power Automate](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Using-Flows/How-to-run-Schedule-Cloud-flow-s-Desktop-Flow-action-by/m-p/1532186) forum but have gotten no working answers.

Comment: Is this an attended or unattended flow?

Comment: This is an attended flow. The VM will be on and running the desktop flow

Answer (score 0):

1. Hope the VM is having power automate machine runtime installed along with PAD.
   2. The VM user should have admin access and the same user credentials to be used
   in run desktop flow action(attended mode) in cloud while creating connections.
   3. This will create a connection and list the desktop top flows available.
   4. PAD and PA cloud to be logged in same work account and environment.

Hope these points will help you.